# Tabularray Undefined Control Sequence "\DeclareRelease" {v2021}

Tags: tables, tabularray

Using lualatex but I encountered an error like this:

> ! Undefined control sequence.
> l.15 \DeclareRelease
> {v2021}{2021-01-01}{tabularray-2021.sty}
> ? x

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It might be relevant in this case to indicate which version of `tabularray` or LaTeX you're using.

Comment: That probably means your LaTeX is too old.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rollback commands `\DeclareRelease` and `\DeclareCurrentRelease` were added to LaTeX kernel in release 2018-04-01 (see this TUGboat [article](https://www.latex-project.org/publications/2018-FMi-TUB-tb122mitt-version-rollback.pdf)).  The error means your TeX distribution is too old.

In fact, here are the first three code lines in `tabularray.sty`.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2018-04-01]
\DeclareRelease{v2021}{2021-01-01}{tabularray-2021.sty}
\DeclareCurrentRelease{}{2022-01-01}
```

The new rollback mechanism in LaTeX is elegant:

- when you write `\usepackage{tabularray}`, you get `tabularray.sty` of version 2022, which requires a LaTeX release in TeX Live 2021 (MiKTeX 21) or newer;
- when you write `\usepackage{tabularray}[=v2021]`, you get `tabularray-2021.sty` of version 2021, which requires a LaTeX release in TeX Live 2020 (MiKTeX 20) or newer.

Therefore you need to update your TeX distribution to use `tabularray` package.